# Python dictionary values to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python3.6.

There is a python dictionary

```
my_dict = {"AUG": {"AA": 10, "BB": 55},
           "SEPT": {"AA": 11, "BB": 56},
           "OCT": {"AA": 12, "BB": 57},
           "NOV": {"AA": 13, "BB": 58},
           "DEC": {"AA": 14, "BB": 59}
     }
```

Get all values of "AA" and "BB" and put in a list.

How to convert my_dict dictionary to this format in optimized way?

```
new_dict = {"AA": [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], "BB": [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]}
```

I am using this to convert but my data is big and its slow in conversion:

```
new_dict = {}
for month, data in my_dict.items():
    for key, value in data.items():
         new_dict.setdefault(key, [])
         new_dict[key].append(value)
print(new_dict)
```

Comment: Hint: one way is to use `collections.defaultdict`

Comment: If you're open to using `pandas` you can do `new_dict 
 = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.values()).to_dict(orient='list')`

Comment: I added my way to convert data in question. but with real data this is slow. I am looking for a optimized way for conversion.

Comment: @pault pandas works !! I learned new thing today. Can you please give example how to use collections.defaultdict in this case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using this to convert but my data is big and its slow in conversion

Here are some speed tests to help you benchmark the different methods:

#### Set up random data

First I'm going to create a random dictionary with 1000 outer_keys and all 2 upper case characters for inner keys with random integer values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
from itertools import combinations, chain, groupby
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

np.random.seed(0)

N = 1000
outer_keys = ["".join(x) for x in np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase), (N, 3))]
outer_keys = list(set(outer_keys))
inner_keys = ["".join(x) for x in combinations(string.ascii_uppercase, 2)]

my_dict = {
    outer_key: {
        inner_key: np.random.randint(0, 100) 
        for inner_key in inner_keys
    }
    for outer_key in outer_keys
}
```

#### Method 1: OP's solution

```
%%timeit
new_dict_op = {}
for month, data in my_dict.items():
    for key, value in data.items():
        new_dict_op.setdefault(key, [])
        new_dict_op[key].append(value)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 89.7 ms per loop
```

#### Method 2: `collections.defaultdict`

```
%%timeit
new_dict_dd = defaultdict(list)
for d in my_dict.values():
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_dict_dd[k].append(v)
#10 loops, best of 3: 48.3 ms per loop
```

#### Method 3: Absurd one-liner using `sorted` (slow) and `itertools.groupby`

```
%%timeit
new_dict_oneliner = {
    k: list(map(itemgetter(1), g)) 
    for k, g in groupby(
        sorted(
            chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items, my_dict.values()))
        ), 
        itemgetter(0)
    )
}
# 1 loop, best of 3: 514 ms per loop
```

#### Method 4: Pandas

```
%%timeit
new_dict_pandas = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.values()).to_dict(orient='list')
# 10 loops, best of 3: 139 ms per loop
```

#### Method 5: Pandas assuming you already have the DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.values())
%%timeit
new_dict_pandas_2 = df.to_dict(orient='list')
# 100 loops, best of 3: 7.99 ms per loop
```

So it seems that using `pandas` is 10x faster than your original method, neglecting the upfront cost of converting to a DataFrame. If you don't have the DataFrame, using a `defaultdict` is 2x faster.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty trivial, but I'm still disappointed you didn't include a coded attempt of your own. (until editing your post 15 minutes later...)

```
my_dict = {"AUG": {"AA": 10, "BB": 55},
           "SEPT": {"AA": 11, "BB": 56},
           "OCT": {"AA": 12, "BB": 57},
           "NOV": {"AA": 13, "BB": 58},
           "DEC": {"AA": 14, "BB": 59}
}

new_dict = {"AA": [], "BB": []}
for item in my_dict.values():
    for key in new_dict:
        new_dict[key].append(item[key])

print(new_dict)
```

Would net you:

> {'AA': [11, 10, 13, 12, 14], 'BB': [56, 55, 58, 57, 59]}

Obviously this output will be different every time from the nature of dictionaries. If that is a problem, you need to implement an `OrderedDict()` instead.

Note: you could probably also condense this to a single line of list/dictionary comprehensions

Comment: Just because it *can* be done in a single line (`{k: list(map(itemgetter(1), g)) for k, g in groupby(sorted(chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items, my_dict.values()))), itemgetter(0))}`) doesn't meant you should. A plain loop is better here, IMO.

Comment: @pault for readability (a very important consideration), yes the expanded form is significantly better. However, it is my understanding that comprehensions are *slightly* faster and OP says he is looking for an "optimized way". Thank you for including the one liner version though!

Comment: Using pandas, a better one-liner would be: `new_dict = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.values()).to_dict(orient='list')`

Comment: can not use this way. because here we hard code keys in my_dict . new_dict = {"AA": [], "BB": []}

Comment: @pault I figured there would be a great `pandas` method too. However, OP did not specify what he was looking for

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with a comprehension

```
result = {k:[d[k] for d in my_dict.values()] for k in ("AA","BB")}

# {'AA': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 'BB': [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]}
```